# Digital snow on external screens Macbook Pro 15" 2016 + USB-C Adapter

Tags: macbook-pro

I have this new Macbook pro and this is what is going on after a while. Might be actually a heating issue since I run it in a clamshell mode. But since I can screenshot it I can assume this is a software problem.

[image]

[image]

It happens when two monitors are plugged in and I think especially after I scroll or open many windows.

After you let it idle it goes back to normal I will check the GPU temperature next time. The strange part is I can screenshot the issue. So I guess that might be drivers fault? The OS is the latest one: Sierra 10.12.4 (16E195) with all updates installed.

It is probably not related to the temperature:

[image]

And the hardware test did not find any defects.

**UPDATE**

After observing it, I think I could say that it happens only with external monitors connected through Apple USB-C -> USB/Lightning/HDMI adaptors.

But the problem is not in the adaptors or I wouldn't be able to screenshot it.

**Update**

Comment: First thing to do is see if it appears in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262). Hold Shift while booting.   If it does, the continue with running [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.  Post your results.

Comment: The problem is I need to "warm it up" first to witness this. Can't reproduce it reliably, but I see this fairly regularly. Will try the test though.

Comment: They made a new MacBook already in 2017?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a hardware GPU problem.  You can run diagnostics by booting the machine while holding D.  Instructions here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

Since this is a pretty new computer I'm sure it will be repaired under warranty (new logic board).  Schedule a genius bar appointment.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue back then I used Mavericks with the mid-2012 model (with GT 650M) especially when I used my transparent terminal window or a java application or the older Safari and that was the worst. I just 'lived' with it but now I changed to a new Mac with fresh OS and I've never experienced this issue since then.
I suggest to recheck if all updates are installed. Maybe give us some thermal parameters just to be sure.
I know this should more be a comment than an answer but I'd like to help, I was annoyed with this as well :-)

Comment: And the same with Mavericks and Early 2011 with 6490M.

Comment: So I guess that's fairly "normal" for dedicated video card?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a 2011 MacBook Pro, which turned out to be a known issue with the physical silicon of the graphics processor.  Apple can run the diagnostic for free if you make an appointment at a Genius bar, although they may charge for a fixed price repair if it turns out to be a hardware issue.